# Dynamic BlazeDS endpoint configuration

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I search for some help creating a web Flex application using BlazeDS and Java server with dynamic BlazeDS endpoint configuration.

First, I will try to explain my current situation.

I have a Flex 3.2 application that provides GUI of the application. From the ActionScript I call Java methods using BlazeDS. To access the BlazeDS I use a Config class that provides the endpoint as shown below (it is a constructor):

```
public function Config(): void {

    if (_serviceUrl == null) {
        try {
            var browser: IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
            browser.init();
            var url: String = browser.url; 
            var host: String = mx.utils.URLUtil.getServerName(url);
            var port: uint = mx.utils.URLUtil.getPort(url);
            var parts: Array = url.split('/');
            if (parts[2] == '') {
                url = DEFAULT_URL;
                Alert.show("Unable to determine server location, using default URL: " + DEFAULT_URL, "Connection error");
            }
            else {
                url = parts[0] + '//' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[3] + '/messagebroker/amf';

            }
            _serviceUrl = url;
        } catch (e: Error) {

            Alert.show("Exception while trying to determine server location, using default URL: " + DEFAULT_URL, "Connection exception");
            _serviceUrl = DEFAULT_URL;
        }
    }

}
```

The idea of the class is to determine the endpoint from the request URL. I use a Delegate class to call the remote methods using BlazeDS like the following:

```
{
import com.adobe.cairngorm.business.ServiceLocator;

import mx.rpc.IResponder;
import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

public class AbstractRemoteDelegate
{
    public function AbstractRemoteDelegate(responder:IResponder,serviceName:String) 
    {
        _responder=responder;
        _locator=ServiceLocator.getInstance();
        _service=_locator.getRemoteObject(serviceName);
        _service.showBusyCursor=true;
        _service.endpoint = Config.instance.serviceUrl;

    }

    private var _responder:IResponder;
    private var _locator:ServiceLocator;
    private var _service:RemoteObject;

    protected function send(operationName:String,... args:Array) : void {           
        _service.getOperation(operationName).send.apply(_service.getOperation(operationName),args).addResponder(_responder);
    }

}
}
```

This approach actually works fine. However, I got across a situation where I can't use dynamically determined URL. In such a situation, I need a hard-coded URL in the Config.as file. And this is the problem. When trying to deploy the application to another server, I always need to rebuild the application with a new URL configuration in the ActionScript class Config.

Therefore I search for a way to define a static configuration for the Flex application to connect to a BlazeDS server. And the way to change such configuration without rebuilding the application so I can give the customer his own way to reconfigure and move the Flex application.

I thought about using a configuration file, but Flex runs on the client side and there is no configuration file!
I thought about using database configuration, but I don't have any database on the client side!

To sum up, I am looking for a way, how to get BlazeDS URL from a configuration to be able to change it without rebuilding the whole app.

Thanks for any useful suggestions.

EDIT: Revised the question to be more actual. I improved the way to determine the URL dynamically from the request URL, so it works now even for proxy server. However, my curiosity persists for the configuration of flex without rebuilding.

Comment: I finally managed to find a way to dynamically detect the correct URL address. However, still I am interested in the way to change flex configuration without the need to rebuild if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an old example [Blaze DS Service](https://github.com/floriansalihovic/spring-blazeds-example/blob/master/client/src/main/flex/de/flashforum/ffk10/beautiful/architectures/services/GreetingService.as) of mine which does basically the same as you did. It's just the string which needs to be created correctly. If the endpoint address is wrong, catch the error accordingly.

My project may currently not build because of Flexmojos ... I'm not able to test that yet.

Since it did not read you question properly, I misunderstood you: You can put a configuration file next to the SWF and load it via URLLoader or pass it via FlashVars. That should give you the freedom to pass the endpoint dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your example. However, I believe it does not solve my problem. You have an URL hard-coded in the code. Therefore you are always connecting to the same URL. When you try to move your application to another server, you have to rebuild the application to replace the URL string.
I am able to hard-code the address as well when I am not able to determine it automatically. However, when hard-coded, I still have to rebuild the application to be able to deploy to new destination.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you in the first place. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Good hint, Florian. So I just place a config file inside the WAR and using URLLoader I am able to access the file in ActionScript without knowing the URL of the server? Can you give some example? Thanks.

Comment: Used this site for examples and seems finally working the way I needed! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf5

Comment: Awesome! Sorry that I wasn't reading your question properly ... that would have had saved some time.